# how to understand openssl

Tags: openssl, ipsec

I am studying Openssl , but didn't getting that openssl is a tool/library.what is its main application and how it will be used?

And how this openssl is related to ipsec, i have studied the ipsec protocol there if i want to configure ipsec ,that openssl has to be installed(required package) why?

please anybody guide me, i am not getting the things correctly.

Comment: Is your question "_how to use openssl to create certificates?_" ? Please post only one question at a time. Remember this is not a forum, you may take lengthy discussions to [the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151/the-dmz)

Comment: also, I would rephrase the title, as it stands a valid answer to the question "how to understand openssl?" would be "reading"

Comment: hi @Purefan i want to know the significance of openssl and its application.

Comment: have you looked at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSL)?

Comment: yeah @Purefan i had gone through it but what i want to know, it is not there. may be you get an idea in below discussion what i am trying for.

Answer (score 3):

[OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/) is a both a software library and a program (the "toolkit") which offers direct access to various features of that library.

A **software library** is a collection of program subroutines which doesn't do anything on its own but which can be used by other programs. In case of OpenSSL, these are [subroutines which implement various cryptographic algorithms and protocols](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/).

That means if a programmer wants to create a program which communicates encrypted, they don't need to implement the SSL protocol from scratch (or even worse, invent an own encryption system). They can simply link their program to the OpenSSL library and use the implementations which it provides.

This has various advantages.

1. The programmer saves a lot of time because there is less program code to type.
2. The programmer doesn't need to understand how the cryptographic primitives work on a deeper level. Cryptography is a very complicated and highly specialized field which very few programmers *really* understand (which is why we have [a separate stackexchange site](https://crypto.stackexchange.com) for it). So the availability of libraries like OpenSSL allows far more programmers to write programs with strong encryption, which benefits you as an end-user.
3. The programmer can use an implementation which is already widely tested by many other users, so it will likely have very few bugs.

IPsec is a protocol which uses a lot of encryption algorithms which are already available in OpenSSL. So the developers of your IPsec implementation likely saw these advantages and decided to make use of it. But that also means that their IPsec implementation doesn't work without it. That's why you need to install OpenSSL in order to enable IPsec.

But there is also a disadvantage: When OpenSSL *does* have a bug, that bug can potentially affect every single program which uses OpenSSL. This can create quite a fuss, like with the [hearthbleed vulnerability](http://heartbleed.com/) in 2014.

Now about the **program tookit** OpenSSL. OpenSSL also comes with a command-line based program named `openssl` which allows to execute various functions from the OpenSSL library directly. For example the command line `openssl dgst -sha256 -hex file.txt` invokes the OpenSSL library function to generate the SHA256 message digest of the file `file.txt` and outputs it as a hexadecimal string. This usage is usually too cumbersome for normal end users, but can be useful for security professionals and server admins.

Comment: Hi @Philipp you have explained in a nice way, now i got some brief idea. so the openssl software library lies in userspace & openssl supports for Transport layer protocols(SSL/TLS) & provides encryption algorithms, but ipsec is a Network layer protocol. If two peers want to communicate or need to exchange information the application request the kernel(socket) and creates the sk_buf instances.Application writes it data to sk_buf, then it will pass through the layers. If a packet needs to be encrypted/decrypted in Network layer i.e in kernel how this software library will be used from userspace.

Comment: @Kumar2080 Libraries can be used by both kernel-space and user-space programs. And IPsec uses many encryption algorithms which are also used by SSL. OpenSSL doesn't just provide SSL but also the individual algorithms, so they can be used by any program which requires cryptographic algorithms, even when it needs them for another purpose than SSL.

Comment: can you please give me some reference, how the kernel uses the user-space app library. I know that if any app uses the library need any kernel services it requests the kernel (through socket/system calls)& kernel will serves the request.

Comment: @Kumar2080 A library is a library. There is no such thing as a "user-space library" (maybe in intention, but there is no technical difference). A kernel-process can call functions from a library just like a user-process can. But in-depth technical details about the inner workings of the Linux kernel are really more of a topic for https://linux.stackexchange.com.